# etcdctl can't see the key put by go client

Tags: etcd3

I run etcd by this command (no more other configuration)

```
./etcd-v3.2.12-linux-amd64/etcd
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints: []string{"http://127.0.0.1:2379"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    _, err = cli.Put(context.TODO(), "abc", "123")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("put succ")
}
```

---

```
./etcd-v3.2.12-linux-amd64/etcdctl get abc
Error:  100: Key not found (/abc) [6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export ETCDCTL_API=3

v2 and v3 are stored separately